# ServiceStack 4 new licensing

Tags: c#, .net, licensing, servicestack

We are using ServiceStack 3 now on a production environment and I checked the new licensing features of ServiceStack 4 and this is what I've found:

10 Operations in ServiceStack (i.e. Request DTOs)
10 Tables in OrmLite
20 Different Types in JSON, JSV and CSV Serializers *
20 Different Types in Redis Client Typed APIs
6000 requests per hour with the Redis Client

I don't understand what is "20 Different Types in JSON, JSV and CSV Serializers". We currently have 3 services in the API and 3 request DTO's and not using the Redis Client so my question is can we update to the free version 4 without encountering any limitations?

Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you should be asking a lawyer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means if you try to serialize/deserialize more than 20 different types you will require a paid license. See the test in the source code [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/LicenseUsageTests.cs#L55). In this case 20 different types are trying to be deserialized, causing a `License Exception`.

From you description, you should be well within the limit of the free license and not have to worry about hitting any limitations.

Comment: Bear in mind that if you would like the introductory pricing on paid license(s) you only have through today to get them and be grandfathered in [source](https://plus.google.com/+DemisBellot/posts/gpb3GsayLPu)